# performSelector:withObject:afterDelay called after the end of a CALayer animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-animation, calayer, performselector

I want to perform an animation of the position of some CALayers. Before the end of the animation, I want to push another `UIViewController` so that when I pop this last UIView controller, the `CALayers` are back in their original positions. This is my code:

```
CABasicAnimation *animation4 = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
animation4.fromValue = [control.layer valueForKey:@"position"];

CGPoint endPoint4=CGPointMake(512, -305);

animation4.toValue =[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:endPoint4];
animation4.duration=1;
[control.layer addAnimation:animation4 forKey:@"position"];

[self performSelector:@selector(goToSolutionViewController) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.9];
```

And in `goToSolutionViewController` I have:

```
-(void)goToSolutionViewController{

    SolutionViewController *solution=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SolutionViewID"];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:solution animated:NO];
```

}

The problem is that

`[self performSelector:@selector(goToSolutionViewController) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.9]`

is not called until the end of the animation. So `goToSolutionViewController` is called after 1.9 seconds instead of 0.9.

What can I do to push the UIViewController before the animation ends? Or to have the `CALayers` back in the original position when I pop the `UIViewController` but the user can't see the way back.

Edit: ---

This performance issue only happens the first time I perform the animation and push the UIViewcontroller. When I pop it and do everything again, the performance is as specter. The problem might be with the UIViewController load time the first time.

Comment: Move the performSelector line before the animation block(?)

Comment: I have the same results but I have noticed that it only happens the first time I do it. If I pop the solutionViewController and do everything again, it works perfect. It may be that it takes more time the first time the navigationcontroller push the uiviewcontroller. How can I control it?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of relying on the timing of the animation compared to performing after a delay you should use one of the animation callbacks to call your method. You can either use a CATransaction, which will allow you to use a block, or the normal delegate methods.

### Using a CATransaction

By wrapping your animation (adding it to the layer) in a transaction you can use the completion block of the transaction.

```
[CATransaction begin];
// Your animation here...
[CATransaction setCompletionBlock:^{
    // Completion here...
}];
[CATransaction commit];
```

### Using the delegate callbacks

By setting yourself as the animations delegate you get a delegate callback when the animation finishes.

```
animation4.delegate = self;
```

And the callback

```
- (void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)anim finished:(BOOL)flag {
    // Completion here..
}
```

Comment: The thing is that I want to call the method before the animation ends.

Comment: @user1419017 That makes very little sense. Why not just make shorter animation?

Comment: I just wanted my CALayers to go back to the original position while I am in another UIViewController so I can't see the way back and when I pop the last UIViewController, I have the CALayers in the same place.

Comment: @user1419017 Unless you actually update the property of the layer it is going to go back to it's original position once the animation is over.